# How to debug a site that crashes iPad Safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, google-maps-api-3, safari

A Google Maps site I am developing at the moment consistently crashes/kills Safari on the iPad every time before it fully loads.

The site checks out as valid HTML5 and valid CSS with the W3C validators and the only JavaScript error related to the site is a variable scope/timing issue I've yet to sort out (to do with google.maps.places) but I can't imagine this is serious enough to kill the browser.

On a Windows PC Safari, IE, Firefox and Chrome are fine. On Ubuntu Firefox is fine. On Android both Firefox and Chrome are fine (though the android browser has a couple of css formatting issues).

I don't know where to start with debugging for Safari on the iPad as the browser just dies and closes with no error, which isn't very helpful.

Where do I start, other the dismantling the site and rebuilding to see which bit breaks the browser?

(The site is at http://www.BlueBadgeParking.com)

I'm already looking in the developer console on the PC version of Safari and can only see that one undefined variable bug mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about remote web inspector for debugging web apps on iOS devices. You need to enable remote web inspector from Settings->Safari->Advanced on your iPad. Then you connect your iPad to Mac and go to Safari's preferences pane under Advance and check the Show Develop menu in the menu bar checkbox.

You should now able to inspect DOM elements, CSS and run JS.

Cheers,
Kumar

Comment: I don't have access to a Mac I'm afraid. I set up the Web Inspector on the iPad earlier and enabled the Developer menu in Safari on the PC but that just looks like a local debug system - or am I not using that properly?

Comment: There's a bit of bad news for using PC. You can only debug using the remote web inspector on a Mac. Safari 6 for windows is not available.

Comment: It actually wouldn't do you any good to have a mac, in this case, because Remote Web Inspector **on the Mac** dies when the browser on the iPad crashes.  I'm having the same issue, I can see that my app is causing Jetsam to kill the WebKit.WebContent process due to "highwater" memory condition.  However, I can't usefully debug the issue because the the remote inspector on the Mac disappears with all logging, profiling info, etc.  Pretty poor tool, IMO.